# Modify live search in Alfresco Commmunity 5.0.d

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and trying to find the files related to live search.

I would like to remove or modify the people finder in live search. Please let me know the files or way to achieve it.

[image]

Share-header.get.js info is below:

```
if (!user.isAdmin)
{
  widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_MY_FILES");
  widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_SHARED_FILES");

  widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_SITES_MENU");
  widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_PEOPLE");

  widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_REPOSITORY");
  widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_BECPG");
}

//Disable people search 
var headerSearch = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_SEARCH");
if (headerSearch)
{ 
  headerSearch.config.showPeopleResults = false;       
  headerSearch.config.placeholder="Search files, sites";      
}
```

Below is extensions.xml

```
<extension>
    <modules>
        <module>
            <id>Update Site Header</id>
            <version>1.0</version>
```

true
            
                
                    
                     org.alfresco.share.header
                        com.site-header
                        
                            share-header

As I added below lines, now I could see that my file, shared file and other menu items being removed for user(non admin) but no changes in search box.

**Credit : Muralidharan**

```
<auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
<evaluator type="default.extensibility.evaluator"/>
```

Screenshot of html structure for search box.
[image: screenshot of html structure]

Below is screenshot of modules/deploy:

[image: modules/deploy]

Screenshot of debug mode :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed below link and it worked like a charm.

https://community.alfresco.com/message/806438-re-not-able-to-disable-suggestion-in-alfresco?commentID=806438&et=watches.email.thread#comment-806438

Summary:
Override the live-search-people.get.json.ftl file to produce no result for live search.

Steps:

1. Extract alfresco-remote-api-5.0.d (/Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib)
2. Goto /Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-remote-api-5.0.d/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search and copy live-search-people.get.json.ftl
3. Then goto Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/search (create new directory if not exist) and paste the file copied earlier
4. Open that file in editor like sublime text and replace with following code.

   <#import "../../repository/person/person.lib.ftl" as personLib/>

   <#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>
   {
      "totalRecords": 0,
      "startIndex": 0,
      "items":
      [
      ]
   }
5. Restart the tomcat and test live search.

Thanks to Angel and Alex for answer followed with clarification.

Interesting finding that I was using Aikau 1.0.8 Because of that the changes recommended by Muralidharan was not working (older version) so now as I move to newer version of Aikau (1.0.101) then those changes are good to go.

Thank you Muralidharan!

/****NOTE****/

If your using older version of Aikau (like 1.0.8) than you have to override the extension
Or
If your using newer version of Aikau (like 1.0.101) than you can directly make changes.

Answer (score 2):

We excluded people search using below script.

```
//Disable people search 
var headerSearch = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_SEARCH");
if (headerSearch)
{ 
  headerSearch.config.showPeopleResults = false;       
  headerSearch.config.placeholder="Search files, sites";      
}
```

And we placed this file, in the following path.
C:\Alfresco5\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\web-extension\site-webscripts\com\quanticate\header\share-header.get.js

Use the module extension to apply your customisation in Share and store this file into alfresco\web-extension\site-data\extensions\extensions.xml

```
<extension>
  <modules>
    <module>
      <id>Menu customisation</id>
      <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
      <evaluator type="default.extensibility.evaluator"/>
       <!-- default.extensibility.evaluator is applied to determine if the module should be executed -->
      <customizations>        
         <customization>
            <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco</targetPackageRoot>
            <sourcePackageRoot>com.quanticate.header</sourcePackageRoot> <!-- Your package path should go here -->
            <alwaysApply>
               <webscript>share-header</webscript>
            </alwaysApply>
         </customization>
      </customizations>
    </module>
  </modules>
</extension>
```

Comment: I have added the script and restarted the tomcat but no change is reflected. Also I have updated my post with my share-header.get.js file info. Any idea?

Comment: Where you have placed the share-header.get.js file ?

Comment: I added module extension details and this should work now for you.

Comment: I already made that change in extensions.xml (updated in post) and path of files are fine. Still not working ...any idea?

Comment: Menu items are getting removed but search is still showing people as suggestion. any idea? thanks

Comment: widgetUtils.deleteObjectFromArray(model.jsonModel, "id", "HEADER_SEARCH"); This command remove the search box but headerSearch.config.showPeopleResults = false;       
  headerSearch.config.placeholder="Search files, sites"; these doing nothing

Comment: Can you check the module extension from http://IP:POST/share/page/modules/deploy page?

Comment: I have updated the post with screenshot of modules/deploy url.

Comment: I followed this and it worked like charm. https://community.alfresco.com/message/806438-re-not-able-to-disable-suggestion-in-alfresco?commentID=806438&et=watches.email.thread#comment-806438

Comment: I have added your code but placeholder is not changing.

Comment: Issue for your changes not working was that I was using older version of Aikau 1.0.8 and now I have upgraded to 1.0.101 so your recommendation works fine.

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the files containing the webscript response. Search for the Freemarker template files which have the rendered output  and over-ride it .

Comment: finding right file is itself difficult and I am new to Alfresco.. if you could tell about which file needs to be changed?

Comment: Live search in Alfresco is implemented in Aikau . The related webscripts are  packaged in share.war .You have to create your own extensions to override the required files as per your requirement.

Comment: Click on "Toggle Developer View" in Debug Menu drop down. That enables you to see the Aikau widget information.  The Widget type you are looking for is alfresco/header/SearchBox .

Comment: added a screenshot, please have a look at it.

Comment: how can I find this file in alfresco community so I could edit it?